# JSON type provider for F#: getting rows/column names

Tags: json, f#, type-providers, f#-data, deedle

I am using trying to use JSON Provider from FSharp.Data
http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/JsonProvider.html

```
type BookOrder = JsonProvider<"../Documents/sample.json">

let commandType = "returnOrderBook" 
let currencyPair = "BTC_NXT"
let depth = string 3

let polReq = "https://poloniex.com/public?" + "command=" + commandType + "&currencyPair=" + currencyPair + "&depth="
+ depth

let BookOrderNow = BookOrder.Load(polReq)
```

> val BookOrderNow : JsonProvider<...>.Root =    {    "asks": [
>        [
>          "0.00001605",
>          14636.67789781
>        ],
>        [
>          "0.00001606",
>          73739.31116785
>        ],
>        [
>          "0.00001607",
>          1342158.7102721
>        ]    ],    "bids": [
>        [
>          "0.00001593",
>          17805.17982312
>        ],
>        [
>          "0.00001591",
>          71659.725
>        ],
>        [
>          "0.00001590",
>          67600.19748428
>        ]    ],    "isFrozen": "0",    "seq": 29534867  }

```
BookOrderNow.Bids
```

> val it : decimal [] [] =    [|[|0.00001593M; 17805.17982312M|];
>   [|0.00001591M; 71659.725M|];
>        [|0.00001590M; 67600.19748428M|]|]

is there a method to get as an output

> ["asks";"bids";"isFrozen";"seq"]

?

and if i did get from some function/method "bids" in some variable `varname` is there a function like (in this particular case)

```
GetJsonContent: JsonProvider<...>.Root -> string -> ???
GetJsonContent BookOrderNow varname
```

and return the value of BookOrderNow.Bids ?

I mean, if we know IN ADVANCE the contents of the JSON file, we don't need to do this, but if we don't, ... ? Ultimately i want to put the data in Deedle Frame / Series objects

Thank you for any advice. This is the first time i'm trying to use this library seriously

Comment: "Type providers are best suited to situations where the schema is stable at runtime and during the lifetime of compiled code."  - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/tutorials/type-providers/creating-a-type-provider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the answer was given to me by @FoggyFinder

```
BookOrderNow.JsonValue.Properties()
   |> Seq.map fst
   |> printfn "%A" //=> seq ["asks"; "bids"; "isFrozen"; "seq"]

let getJsonContent (x:BookOrder.Root) varname =
    x.JsonValue.GetProperty varname
    |> JsonExtensions.AsArray
    |> Array.map
        (JsonExtensions.AsArray >> Array.map (JsonExtensions.AsDecimal))
```

However, as per the comment from @Matiasd ,

"Type providers are best suited to situations where the schema is stable at runtime and during the lifetime of compiled code."

Thank you to both of you